# Cannot convert template argument to the actual type being passed

Tags: c++, templates

Here's a fully reproducible PoC of the problem, posted on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/x78Ksro88.

I'm encountering the following problem: the compiler is reporting an error because it cannot convert argument 2 (in the `search_in` function) from type `T` to the actual type in a situation where `T` represents a template type.

```
template <typename T>    
void analyze(vegtable& type, const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& dee, T& pee, int ole, std::uint16_t cee)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case type::banana:

        beta::search_in(dee, pee, ole, cee);
        break;

    case type::orange:

        gemma::search_in(dee, pee, ole, cee);
        break;

    case type::lemon:
        
        zeta::search_in(dee, pee, ole, cee);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

`vegetable` is a typed class enum of type `std::uint8_t`.

I call the analyze function as follows (`sample` is of type `potato`):

```
analyze<potato>(organic, data, sample, 12);
```

where some of the types are defined as follows, for example:

```
vegetable organic;

organic = vegetable::banana;

struct potato
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

potato sample;
```

If I delete the function calls for the switch cases `type::orange:` and `type::lemon:`, the code compiles and works as expected, but if I leave the analyze function as shown, the compiler throws the error stated in the prologue of this question. This is a weird behaviour!

Note: there are other types too that I pass with the `T` argument other than the `potato` type, as shown in the PoC.

I can guarantee at the time of calling the `analyze` function, that the `T` type passed to each of the cases through the `search_in` function call is of the correct type. It seems that the compiler is not able to figure it out!

Comment: how can you convert potato to tomato?

Comment: Old deleted question for context: [Cannot convert template argument to the actual type being passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78241223/cannot-convert-template-argument-to-the-actual-type-being-passed#78241223)

Comment: The error is straightforward. How is the compiler supposed to bind a `tomato&` to a `potato`?

Comment: in your function you call `gemma::search_in(dee, pee, ole, cee)` with `pee` being a `potato`.  That won't work since the function expects a `tomato`.

Comment: Your function `gamma::search_in` takes `tomato` but template `T` is `potato`.

Comment: @foragerDev and @NathanOliver, well, before calling the `analyze` function, I set the correct `enum` type. So, if I'm "calling" `case type::orange`, and I already know that `pee` in `gemma::search_in()` takes an object of type `tomato`, then I expect it to work. I thought the compiler would be able to figure it out.

Comment: If this is not possible, is there any other way around it?

Comment: Nope.  All code paths are still checked by the compiler to make sure the entire code compiles.  Just because you gave it the right enum to get the right case statement doesn't mean that is always going to happen so all case statements are checked for correctness.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I see! Any suggestions to rewrite it and make it work are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect that since you passed to correct enum value that only the case that matters is called, and you are correct in that, the issue is that if the enum value does not match the correct case, then you are calling the wrong function.  Since none of this checking is done at compile time the compiler is forced to check the entire function to make sure all paths compile and in your case they do not.

Since all of you `search_in` functions are the same except for `pee` parameter there is no reason to even use a switch case statement and instead you can just rely on overload resolution to call the correct function for you like:

```
template <typename T>    
void analyze(vegetable& place, const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& dee, T& pee, int ole, std::uint16_t cee)
{
    using beta::search_in;
    using gemma::search_in;
    using zeta::search_in;

    search_in(dee, pee, ole, cee);
}
```

You can see this working with your example code in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/KbY7v6WPK).

Comment: @Xigma No problem. Do note that you also no longer need the `vegetable& place` parameter.